# What's the meaning of recursive noexcept()?

Tags: c++, noexcept

The standard library defines an swaps for arrays and `std::pair` like so:

```c++
template <class T, size_t N>
void swap(T (&a)[N],
          T (&b)[N]) noexcept(noexcept(swap(*a, *b)));

template <class T1, class T2>
struct pair {
    …
    void swap(pair& p) noexcept(noexcept(swap(first,  p.first)) &&
                                noexcept(swap(second, p.second)));
    …
};
```

Effective Modern C++ Item 14 says:

> […] whether they are `noexcept` depends on whether the expression inside the `noexcept` clauses are `noexcept`.
>   Given two arrays of `Widget`, for example, swapping them is `noexcept` only if swapping individual elements in the arrays is `noexcept`, i.e. if swap for `Widget` is `noexcept`.
>   That, in turn, determines whether other swaps, such as the one for arrays of arrays of `Widget`, are `noexcept`.
>   Similarly, whether swapping two `std::pair` objects containing `Widget`s is `noexcept` depends on whether swap for `Widget`s is `noexcept`.

But from this explanation, I cannot understand why it's necessary to nest the call as `noexcept(noexcept(swap(*a, *b)))`.

If the goal is "swapping two arrays should be as `noexcept` as swapping elements", why doesn't `noexcept(swap(*a, *b))` suffice?

Are these different overloads of `noexcept()` or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not "recursive" `noexcept`, there simply are two uses of the `noexcept` keyword:

- [`noexcept` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) - which marks a function as `noexcept` and optionally takes a *boolean constant expression* as an argument
- [`noexcept` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) - which takes an *expression* as an argument and returns a *boolean constant expression* representing whether or not the *expression* is `noexcept`

---

In your case:

```
//          `noexcept` operator
//          v~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   noexcept(noexcept(swap(*a, *b)))
// ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// `noexcept` specifier
```

Comment: Gotta hate the syntax

Comment: I think the specifier should be renamed to `noexcept_if`.